# How to change GitHub Account in Visual Studio Code

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I have my first GitHub account logged in my Visual Studio Code. A window popped out and I logged in my GitHub credentials there and after that I configured my credentials using the ***git config --global user.email "email@email.com"*** and ***git config --global user.email "username"***.

However when I tried to use my other GitHub account by configuring it to the vscode terminal using ***--global user.email*** and ***--global user.name***, I get errors whenever I add the origin link of the new repository and push it to the new repository.

Here are the following errors that I got while configuring:

1. remote: Repository not found.
2. error: src refspec main does not match any

How can I change it? Thank you!

Comment: What are the errors you get with the other account?

Comment: Here are the following errors that I got while configuring:

1. remote: Repository not found.
2. error: src refspec main does not match any

Thank you!

Comment: you can also create multiple origins by renaming "origin" to any word of your choice and then sequence it with that new name

Answer (score 3):

if you using windows, You need to remove the old account in Windows Credential Manager. After that you will be ask to enter your (new) credentials while doing a git push.